# Getting multiple users for basic auth, spring boot security

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding, spring-security, bcrypt

I have a list of users, and I want to use them in my basic auth.

MY code currently looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();}
  @Autowired
  private ConfigService configService;
  // Authentication : User --> Roles
  // NoOpPasswordEncoder has been deprecated in Spring security so {noop} is being used to avoid errors
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
      .withUser("someuser")
        .password("somepassword")
        .roles("USER");
  }

  // Authorization : Role -> Access
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .httpBasic()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
            .permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/tokenservice/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
          .antMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
        .and().csrf()
        .disable()
          .headers()
          .frameOptions()
        .and().disable()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  }}
```

I want to replace "someuser" and "somepassword" with usernames and passwords from my list of users. Currently I can get the list with `configService.getCOnfigurations().getUsers()`.
A user just has a username and a password, both strings. How do I go about getting all the usernames and all the passwords into `.withUser()`?

**EDIT
I made a simple for loop in the configure, that should do it, but whenever i try to post to my API, it says `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder:99 - Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`

I used an online bcrypt generator to generate the passwords, and they look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configurations>
    <Port>8007</Port>
    <EnableHttps>true</EnableHttps>
    <KeyStorePath>classpath:ssl-server.jks</KeyStorePath>
    <KeyPass>changeit</KeyPass>
    <TokenTtlMillis>15000</TokenTtlMillis>
  <Users Username="user1">
      <Password>$2y$10$.8VQR6tJub5uVdVLByItQO8QYGZVuWPhLuBUTQSDJAvVpLAUmuqZ2</Password>
  </Users>
  <Users Username="user2">
    <Password>$2y$10$r/CQz7PZp5banmSzr9OiDe2Kxrda4BhXIBXvvouRnm1w3M72wLQj.</Password>
  </Users>
</Configurations>
```

the passwords are in plain just password and password2

Comment: From where do you need to get the users and passwords? You're currently using in-memory authentication; do you intend on continuing to use that? (I would recommend you don't, for what it's worth.)

Comment: The users are in an xml file. I sort of fixed my issue with a simple for loop, but now it says the encoded passwords dont look like BCrypt whenever i try to post to my API. Ive used an online BCrypt tool to generate the passwords in the xml file.

What would you do instead of `inMemoryAuthentication()`?

Also do you know a fix to my problem? :<

Comment: I'd use a database, personally. For example, PostgreSQL has an [encryption extension that allows you to create BCrypt hashes of plain-text strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html), e.g. on insert. As for your issue, it may be an issue with how the passwords were encoded when you used the online tool. Try encoding them yourself in a utility that uses your BCrypt library from Spring directly.

Comment: This would be smart yes, but i have to have my credentials stored like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Claudio's answer with the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new MyUserDetailsService();
}
```

The `UserDetailsService` is where the real meat of your code would be. You would provide a custom implementation of the interface that reads from your XML. Assuming that you have a method `getPassword(String username)`:

```
// Adding this import to demontrate where "User" is coming from
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public User loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        return new User(username, getPassword(username), Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")));
    }

    private String getPassword(String username) {
        // Get password from your XML
    }
}
```

As for your BCrypt issue, the `password` hash gives me an invalid salt revision error. Try using your app directly to hash it, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("password"));
}
```

Or to pass in a file with a password on each line (using Java 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Requires 1 parameter that points to a file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    if (!f.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Not a file: " + f);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(f.toPath())) {
        lines.map(encoder::encode)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

That will give you the Spring-generated hashes which you can then insert into your XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `DaoAuthentificationProvider` in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like this:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

and give it your implementation of a `passwordEncoder` and a `userDetailsService`,
for which you have to implement the respective interfaces and their methods.

And then you can assign your `authenticationProvider` in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class like this:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

This way, your `UserDetailService` will provide all the available users and their credentials and you don't have to worry about that in the security configuration.

This way you can store the credentials in whatever way you want (simple file, nosql DB like MongoDB, etc.) and even change that implementation without impact on the way you authenticate with spring security.

Your UserDetailService should look somewhat like this:

```
public class SecUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = userRepository().findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        } else {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getName()));

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getName(), user.getPassword(),
                    grantedAuthorities);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I've used a `UserRepository` that takes care of loading all users from the storage of your choice. E.g. if you decide to store it in a file, it will load all users and their passwords from a file, and provide the method `findByUsername` that gives back the `User` object if one with a matching name is found. Your Repository can also take care of deleting users or modifying their names if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this on spring boot 2.x, with getting users credentials from the console on server start; you can easily change it to load users from file or any other source:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Note: 
        // Use this to enable the tomcat basic authentication (tomcat popup rather than spring login page)
        // Note that the CSRf token is disabled for all requests
        log.info("Disabling CSRF, enabling basic authentication...");
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() // These urls are allowed by any authenticated user
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        log.info("Setting in-memory security using the user input...");

        String username = null;
        String password = null;

        System.out.println("\nPlease set the admin credentials for this web application (will be required when browsing to the web application)");
        Console console = System.console();

        // Read the credentials from the user console: 
        // Note: 
        // Console supports password masking, but is not supported in IDEs such as eclipse; 
        // thus if in IDE (where console == null) use scanner instead:
        if (console == null) {
            // Use scanner:
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Username: ");
                username = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Password: ");
                password = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Confirm Password: ");
                String inputPasswordConfirm = scanner.nextLine();

                if (username.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: user must be set - please try again");
                } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: password must be set - please try again");
                } else if (!password.equals(inputPasswordConfirm)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: password and password confirm do not match - please try again");
                } else {
                    log.info("Setting the in-memory security using the provided credentials...");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            scanner.close();
        } else {
            // Use Console
            while (true) {
                username = console.readLine("Username: ");
                char[] passwordChars = console.readPassword("Password: ");
                password = String.valueOf(passwordChars);
                char[] passwordConfirmChars = console.readPassword("Confirm Password: ");
                String passwordConfirm = String.valueOf(passwordConfirmChars);

                if (username.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Username must be set - please try again");
                } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Password must be set - please try again");
                } else if (!password.equals(passwordConfirm)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Password and Password Confirm do not match - please try again");
                } else {
                    log.info("Setting the in-memory security using the provided credentials...");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

        // Set the inMemoryAuthentication object with the given credentials:
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(password);
            manager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(encodedPassword).roles("USER").build());
        }
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```